# Creating dynamic ABC class based on user defined class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, introspection

I'm writing an plugin framework and I want to be able to write a decorator `interface`, which will convert user class to ABC class and substitute all methods with abstractmethods. I cannot get it working and I suppose the problem is connected with wrong mro, but I can be wrong.

I basically need to be albe to write:

```
@interface
class X:
    def test(self):
        pass

x = X() # should fail, because test will be abstract method.
```

substituting methods with their abstract versions is straightforward (you have to iterate over func's and replace them with `abc.abstractmethod(func)`), but I've got problem with creating dynamic type, which will be an `ABCmeta` metaclass.

Right now I've got something like:

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class Interface(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

def interface(cls):
    newcls = type(cls.__name__, (Interface, cls), {})
    # substitute all methods with abstract ones
    for name, func in inspect.getmembers(newcls, predicate=inspect.isfunction):
        setattr(newcls, name, abstractmethod(func))
    return newcls
```

but it doesnot work - Ican initialize class X without errors.

With standard usage of ABC in Python, we can write:

```
class X(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def test(self):
        pass

x = X() # it will fail
```

How can I create dynamic type in Python3, which will behave like it will have metaclass `ABCmeta` and will substitute all functions with abstract ones?

Comment: Should the `interface` function be returning something? (I'm getting `x = X() # should fail, because test will be abstract method.`).

Comment: of course, sorry for the typo, `interface` should be decorator returning new class :) - I've fixed the question

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) does state that `Dynamically adding abstract methods to a class, or attempting to modify the abstraction status of a method or class once it is created, are not supported`, which explains why it's not working. I'm looking into whether there is still a way to do it.

Comment: But theoretically I'm not trying to add or modify abstraction status of a method (...) - I'm trying to create NEW type based on that old type - If you do this in code - you create something like `class Y(X): @abstractmethod def test2(self): pass` it works, so I should be able to do this with dynamic code (even copying the function dict over new type)

Comment: To the contrary, you do modify each of the functions to be abstract after creating it. Your code first creates the `newcls` class, *then* applies the `abstractmethod` decorator dynamically. (I thus tried reversing the order, first applying `abstractmethod` to `cls`'s methods then creating `newcls`, but it didn't work either).

Comment: I've tried it too. But I really feel there should be a way to do this. We can think about it as we modify the methods and then CREATE new class with metaclass.

Comment: Figured it out, see answer below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is not to use `setattr` to reset each of the attributes, but *instead* to pass those modified attributes to the `type` function as a dictionary:

```
import inspect
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Interface(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    pass

def interface(cls):
    attrs = {n: abstractmethod(f)
             for n, f in inspect.getmembers(cls, predicate=inspect.isfunction)}

    return type(cls.__name__, (Interface, cls), attrs)

@interface
class X(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def test(self):
        pass

x = X()
# does fail:
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
#     x = X() # should fail, because test will be abstract method.
# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class X with abstract methods test
```

Comment: I've created the same code right now! thank you for yours help! :)

Comment: @danilo2: I set it up to inherit both `Interface` and `cls` since you also need to include the non-function members. If there are cases where this becomes a problem and it shouldn't inherit `cls`, you can use `f: abstractmethod(f) if inspect.isfunction(f) else f` in the dict comprehension